# Django create/update multiple models in one rest request

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I have a form in Vue which takes in data that is spread into multiple models when sent to django .

Rest JSON is

```
    data = {
  people:{
    name: "MyName",
    age: 34

  },
  classes:{
    name:"Valgris",
    tag:3492,
    comment:"gob gdjoisu is tsutsi"

  }
}
```

-THE MODELS FIELD IN DJANGO ARE

```
class Classes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_ max_length=50) 
    age = models.IntegerField() 

class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_ max_length=50) 
    tag = models.IntegerField() 
    comment= models.TextField()
```

--- I tried tried using perform_create in my view, and also use create in serializer  but I am unable to do it. **request.data** does not seem to like me popping out data and saving the result. It just doesn't work well.

Is there a way out. or do I have to send two request to **create** People and **Classes** model

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use two request for your purpose.
As `serializer` of `django-rest-framework` requires your `request.data` as an argument,

```
yourSerializer(yourModel, data=request.data)
```

so it will not operate with the data of two models that you are sending from `vue`.
Also, If you want to do these `API` calls with one another then you can call other `API` inside the first one `API`'s response.

```
axios
  .post("first/API/call/url", dataModel1, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
   })
  .then((response) => {
     console.log(response); 
     axios
       .post("second/API/call/url", dataModel2, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        })
       .then((response) => {
           console.log(response); 
       })
       .catch((error) => {
           console.log(error);
     });

   })
   .catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
   });
```

Note: popping out data and changing it is fine for one model but for two model it's not fine.